# Buggy call to WSACleanup() kills WSAStartup()

Tags: c++, dll, tcp, wsastartup, wsacleanup

I have application that is running TCP server. To initialize TCP I run `WSAStartup()`. Then I need to load third party dll. Dll is also does some TCP job and has some bug - it runs `WSACleanup()` without running `WSAStartup()`. This bug brakes my TCP server since dll's `WSACleanup()` kills it.

I can't fix dll. How to avoid this situation. Looks run use dll and my TCP server in different threads doesn't helps

Comment: Don't know if it would make a difference, but could you defer your call to `WSAStartup()` until after you've loaded the 3rd-party DLL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [`WSAStartup` doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `WSAStartup`/`WSACleanup` perform internal reference counting. Therefore all you need to do is call `WSAStartup` twice.

Thus, when your library calls `WSACleanup`, it will only reduce the internal count by one and not release all resources.